# Error while sending trade commands to bybit testnet

Tags: margin, currency, bybit

I am using Alertatron to send manual alerts to bybit testnet exchange. I am getting the following error log. Please let me know what the issue is

======error start==

> [v283, bybit, jothibybit, EOSUSD] ::: market(side=buy, amount=1);
> Script market v1.0.0, by Alertatron
> using buy offset of 0 from 2.884 (current price) --> 2.884
> [bybit, jothibybit, EOSUSD] Executing market order to buy 1.
> Not enough margin to cover order that size [post /v2/private/order/create] - status code: 30031
> Session 40b71524 has no more commands to process on bybit (jothibybit), EOSUSD - waiting for background processes...
> bybit : jothibybit : No active background processes for EOSUSD. Done.
> Session 40b71524 finished waiting for related background tasks
> Request to close exchange connection bybit, jothibybit. Not being used any more.
> Bybit closed
> Bot entering idle state - updating to latest release.
> ===end log

my code

```
jothibybit(EOSUSD){
exchangeSettings(leverage=cross);
cancel(which=all);
 market(side=buy, amount=1);
}
#bot
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error means that you do not have enough money on your Bybit account to execute the trade.

The reason for that can be, that you have not enough money, then you need to reduce the trade size, or you are trying to execute the trade from a subaccount, which is somehow not working properly. in case you are using a subaccount API Key on Bybit, try to execute the trades using a Main Account API Key.

In both cases double check on Alertatron if you have access to the Bybit balance, by running a Manual Alert:

https://alertatron.com/docs/automated-trading/balance
While you are executing that test trade, you should open the "live bot output" in Alertatron, to see the response you get from Bybit.

If that works, try to execute an example trade:
https://alertatron.com/docs/automated-trading/api-keys-bybit